# Rejected request to participate in Google AdSense (Phase 1)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, seo, adsense

I am trying to register my web app for the service of `Google AdSense`.

After five attempts are still stuck in the first phase for the error: **Content insufficient**.

My web app is a search engine for youtube, developed with `AngularJ`s and `NodeJs`

AngularJS fully embraces the asynchronous model and this is what creates problems for `Google's crawlers`. So I implemented the library [prerender.io](https://prerender.io) and I have set up the meta tag to fix any problems with the `#` of Angular.

```
<meta name = "fragment" content = "">
```

I also prepared the `sitemap.xml` within the site, and that index the pages through the portal of google for webmasters.

The site being a search engine, `does not have static content` and reach, so I also added some texts and descriptions in the page principle, which houses the other partial files.

Despite these changes, I could not pass the first stage, how can I do to fix?

I'm not making all the necessary steps for a web app Angular?

Comment: even my social networking nodejs website(http://frienstr.com) has not been accepted.Dont know what one should do to get a dynamic website accepted :(

Answer (score 1):

To be approved in Google Adsense you need about 10 topics of 400 words. The content should be unique. According to Google Adsense TOS it is not allowed to put ads in pages having copied content. So in your case if you provide search results you will provide copied content.